# What is difference between == and === in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, equality-operator

What is the difference between the comparison operators `==` and `===` in Kotlin?

```
class A {
  var foo = 1
}
    
var a1 = A()
var a2 = A()
    
println(a1 == a2)  // output false
println(a1 === a2) // output false
    
a1 = a2 
       
println(a1 == a2)  // output true
println(a1 === a2) // output true
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Kotlin, two types of equality are available. These are: **Structural Equality** & **Referential Equality**.

```
class A {
  var foo = 1
}

var a1 = A()
var a2 = A()
```

Here `a1` and `a2` are two instances of class `A`.

```
println(a1 == a2)
```

It prints `false` because `a1` and `a2` are not structurally equal.

```
println(a1 === a2)
```

It prints `false` because `a1` and `a2` are not referencing the same object.

But, if you execute this line: `a1 = a2` then,

a1 and a2 will be structurally equal and a1 is referencing to the a2 instance. That's why,

```
println(a1 == a2)
println(a1 === a2)
```

both these lines returns true.

Comment: Why are `a1` and `a2` not structurally equal?

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It presents two cases in which the two operators return identical values. It would be more interesting to show a case where they differ.

Answer (score 26):

Briefly speaking, from [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html):

In Kotlin there are two types of equality:

- Structural equality (a check for `equals()`) => `==`
- Referential equality (two references point to the same object) => `===`

Detailed answer:

#### Structural Equality (`==`)

The negated counterpart of `==` is `!=`

By convention, an expression like `a == b`  is translated to:

```kotlin
a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)
```

if `a` is not `null`, it calls the `equals(Any?)` function, otherwise it checks that `b` is referentially equal to `null`.

*To provide a custom equals check implementation*, **override the `equals(other: Any?): Boolean` function**. Functions with the same name and other signatures, like equals(other: Foo) , don't affect equality checks with the operators `==`  and `!=`.

#### Referential Equality (`===`)

The negated counterpart of `===` is `!==`

`a === b` evaluates to `true` if and only if `a` and `b`  point to the same object. For values which are represented as primitive types at runtime (for example, `Int` ), the `===`  equality check is equivalent to the `==` check.

#### Code explanation

Let's assume the definition of `A` is as you have defined in your question.

#### Snippet 1

```kotlin
>>> var a1 = A()
>>> var a2 = A()
>>> a1 == a2 // a1 and a2 are different instances of A
false
>>> a1 == a1
true
>>> a2 == a2
true
>>> a1 === a2 // a1 and a2 have references to different objects
false
```

For regular classes, the implementation of `equals` is inherited from `Any`, and just make the object equal to itself.

#### Snippet 2

```kotlin
>>> var a1 = A()
>>> var a2 = A()
>>> a1 = a2 
>>> a1 == a2
true
>>> a1 === a2
true
```

`a1` and `a2` point to the same object that is why `a1 == a2` and `a1 === a2` return true.

#### Snippet 3

Let's override `equals(Any?)` of `A` as follows:

```kotlin
class A {
    var foo = 1
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other == null || other !is A)
            return false
        return foo == (other as A).foo
    }
}
```

Now let's run the following:

```
>>> var a1 = A()
>>> var a2 = A()
>>> a1 == a2
true
>>> a1 === a2
false
```

Notice that `a1` and `a2` are structurally equal even though they reference difference objects.

Comment: Misleading answer! In snippet 2, a1 === a2 should be false.

Comment: @SriyankSiddhartha No that will be true, as a1 = a3 written above, so now points(reference) to same memory location

Comment: I thought the same thing as @SriyankSiddhartha at first. Snippet 2 would be less confusing if it said `var a2 = a1` instead of `var a2 = A(); a1 = a2`, where the last statement is easy to overlook as it resembles the equality tests.

Comment: Regarding "For regular classes, the implementation of equals is inherited from Any, and just make the object equal to itself," it would be helpful to note that String overrides `equals()` to provide a proper content equality check, but Array doesn't (surprise!).

Answer (score 3):

Structural Equality means content should be same

```
"checks for equals() or ==".
```

Referential Equality means both instances should be pointed to same pointer.

```
"two objects points to same reference or ==="
```

You can override equals() and do the stuff as below.

```
class Person(val p : String) {

  override fun toString(): String = "Person(p$p)"
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if(other == null || other !is Person) {
           return false
        }
       return p == other.p
    }
}
```

lets test this.

```
var a = Person("abc")
var b = Person("abc")

Line 1 => println(a == b)
Line 2 => println(a === b)
```

Line1 prints "true"

Line2 prints "false"

```
a = b
```

Line1 prints "true"

Line2 prints "true"

Finally,

=== always checks for reference equality while == checks for equivalent content and is based on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin == and === operators (fresh look : 6 cases)

In Kotlin if a and b represent two variables then println(a==b) checks whether the two
values are structurally equal or not. But println(a===b) checks whether a and b are
having the same reference or not. Following examples would make this clear.

```
// Case 1 : a and b are both Int
// EqCase1.kt
fun main() {
    var a = 5
    var b = 7
    println(a==b) // false
    //println(a===b) // identity equality for Int is deprecated
    a = b
    println(a==b) // true
    //println(a===b) // identity equality for Int is deprecated
}


// Case 2 : a and b are Double and Integer
// EqCase2.kt
fun main() {
    var a = 5.0
    var b = 7
    //println(a==b) //  operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Double' and 'Int'
    //println(a===b) // operator '===' cannot be applied to 'Double' and 'Int'
    //a = b // inferred type is Int but Double was expected
    //println(a==b) //  inferred type is Int but Double was expected
    println(a===b) // identity equality for Int is deprecated
}


// case 3 : a and b are mathematically same but of different types (Double and Any(say Int))
// EqCase3.kt
fun Eq(a: Double,b: Any) =  if (a == b) "(a == b) is true" else "(a == b) is false"
//fun Eq1(a: Double,b: Any) =  if (a === b) "(a === b) is true" else "(a === b) is false"
fun main() {
    println(Eq(5.0,5)) // (a == b) is false
    //println(Eq1(5.0,5)) 
}

/* O/p
EqCase3.kt:5:34: warning: identity equality for arguments of types Double and Any can be unstable because of implicit boxing
fun Eq1(a: Double,b: Any) =  if (a === b) "(a === b) is true" else "(a === b) is false"
*/


// Case 4 : a and b are both Booleans
// EqCase4.kt
fun main() {
    var a = true
    var b = false
    println(a==b) // false
    //println(a===b) // identity equality for arguments of Boolean is deprecated
    a = b
    println(a==b) // true
    //println(a===b) // identity equality for arguments of Boolean is deprecated
}


// Case 5 : a and b are both Strings
// EqCase5.kt
fun main() {
    var a = "Anil"
    var b = "Vijay"
    println(a==b) // false
    println(a===b) // false
    a = b
    println(a==b) // true
    println(a===b) // true
}


// Case 6 : a and b are both of type arrayOf
// EqCase6.kt
fun main() {
    var a = arrayOf("A","B","C")
    var b = arrayOf("a","b","c")
    println(a==b) // false
    println(a===b) // false
    a = b
    println(a==b) // true
    println(a===b)  // true
}
```